Get number of subfolder count (Only Top Level)
I have a text file with Folder Paths which looks like this
Folder1
Folder1/SubFolder1
Folder1/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder1
Folder1/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder2
Folder1/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder3
Folder1/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder4
Folder1/SubFolder2
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder1
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder2
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder3
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder4
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder5
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6/SubSubSubFolder1
Folder1/SubFolder3
Folder2
Folder2/SubFolder1
Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder1
Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder2
Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder3
Folder2/SubFolder1/SubSubFolder4
Folder2/SubFolder2
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder1
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder2
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder3
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder4
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder5
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder7
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6/SubSubSubFolder1
Folder2/SubFolder3
Folder2/SubFolder4

Now What I want is a dictionary of string and int which saves folder name and count
number of files/folder in it (only Top Level)
Folder1, 3                  // SubFolder1, SubFolder2, SubFolder3
Folder1/SubFolder1,4            // SubSubFolder1, SubSubFolder2, SubSubFolder3, 
Folder1/SubFolder2,6       //SubSubFolder1, SubSubFolder2, SubSubFolder3, SubSubFolder4, SubSubFolder5, SubSubFolder6
Folder1/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6,1         //SubSubSubFolder1
Folder1/SubFolder3,0
Folder2,4                // SubFolder1, SubFolder2, SubFolder3, SubFolder4
Folder2/SubFolder1,4        // SubSubFolder1, SubSubFolder2, SubSubFolder3, SubSubFolder4
Folder2/SubFolder2,7       // SubSubFolder1, SubSubFolder2, SubSubFolder3, SubSubFolder4, SubSubFolder5, SubSubFolder6, SubSubFolder7
Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder6,1             //SubSubSubFolder1
Folder2/SubFolder3,0  
Folder2/SubFolder4,0 

I can iterate it over all lines , but I guess it will get a bit complicated and messy
 var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
 foreach (var line in allLines)
 {
    var subFolderCount = 0;
    var subFolderPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, line);
   //...
 }

but I was wondering is there any easier and efficient way to do this?

So you dont want to use File methods to check how many files/folders are actually in that folder but simply check this text file content?

Yes @TimSchmelter, Checking directly from file/folder would have been easy Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, TopDirectoryOnly) but I have this text file only

@Pankay: Why is "SubSubFolder4/Folder1/SubFolder2" in that dictionary? It's not a line in the file

@TimSchmelter, Corrected it, Must have been a mistake while typing.

Why are Folder2/SubFolder4,0 etc present when for example Folder2/SubFolder2/SubSubFolder7,0 is not? barring that it looks like a simple allLines.ToLookup(Path.GetDirectoryName).Select(l => $"{l.Key},{l.Count()}")

So as commented you just want to analyze the file content, not the actual folders in your OS, then this should work as expected:
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetTopLevelFolderCount(IList<string> lines)
{
    return lines
        .GroupBy(l => l)
        .ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => lines.Count(l => l.StartsWith(g.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                  && l[g.Key.Length..].Count(c => c == '/') == 1));
}

Edit: here's a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iitkb9

An efficient way to handle this is to fill a tree with the data.
First we define a TreeNode:
public class TreeNode
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> _children = new();

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, TreeNode> Children => _children;

    public void Push(IEnumerable<string> pathParts)
    {
        var currentNode = this;
        foreach (var pathPart in pathParts)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.GetOrCreateChildNode(pathPart);
        }
    }

    private TreeNode GetOrCreateChildNode(string pathPart)
    {
        if (_children.TryGetValue(pathPart, out var childNode))
            return childNode;

        childNode = new TreeNode();
        _children[pathPart] = childNode;
        return childNode;
    }
}

Then we create a root node and fill the tree from here:
var rootNode = new TreeNode();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
{
    rootNode.Push(line.Split('/'));
}

Finally we traverse the tree to display desired information:
void Print(TreeNode treeNode, string path)
{
    foreach (var kvp in treeNode.Children)
    {
        var subPath = path is "" ? kvp.Key : path + '/' + kvp.Key;
        Console.WriteLine($"{subPath}, {kvp.Value.Children.Count}");
        Print(kvp.Value, subPath);
    }
}

And call it like that:
Print(rootNode, string.Empty);

Working code available here.
